# How does "input type=number" show an error message if the user inputs "five hundreds"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-input

If the user does not type a number in the field (for instance "five hundred", or "9987-"), angular does not handle it as an error, and no error is shown (the ng-class is not changed in this example).

```
<div class="form-group"
     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && form.price.$error.pattern }">
        <input name="price" id="price" type="number"
               ng-model="formOb.price"
               ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?$/"
                />
```

Is there a way to handle that ? How could the class be changed to 'has-error' ?
(it would be better if no direct javascript is used, if possible)

Comment: `type='number'` shouldn't allow non-numbers

Comment: Give `input` a `name` attribute with value `price`.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to add the input name attribute @robin-james-kerrison

Comment: @maioman, of course, it shouldn't. The question is, when a non-number is input, how could it show an error message, preferably by using the same has-error class.

Comment: In the end, I have set the type as a "text", using the correct ng-pattern to handle all non-numbers correctly, regardless if they were 'caught' by the "type=number" attributes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set the type as a "text"** - Angular will catch this via ng-pattern - if you use type="number", then some browser may not even pass the input value to be checked with your pattern.

```
<div class="form-group"
     ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && form.price.$error.pattern }">
        <input name="price" id="price" type="text"
               ng-model="formOb.price"
               ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?$/"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-pattern works only when you bind html tag with name. Only name attribute is required for making you example up and running.

Check this link for more details:
[Angularjs Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to add the input name attribute.